# Play a video top of the tracked image in Ar.js

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I am trying to play a video after the image has been tracked.
But I couldn't do that. I can hear the sound of the video but can't get the video to the top of the image. 
The code is below.

https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/13d94c52-526b-481b-900f-872bd598f3d7

This is the tracking image

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/examples/image-tracking/nft/trex-image-big.jpeg

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please at least try and explain what did you try out yourself? Also do show some code snippets of the problem instead of expecting people to troubleshoot this themself and provide a solution for you.

Comment: hey I am looking for quite something similar: I want to project 3 images ontop of a mural. Do you have a tutorial on how you did your project?

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's nothing wrong in your code, but actually the nft feature is quite experimental and there are some optimizations still to do. Possible way to solve for now: adding a `side="double"` to the  primitive and trying to use a smaller video reducing the size of the width and adjust the compression.

Another problem could be the descriptors (the **NFT** marker) that you are using, if it has low dpi and not sufficient width the image to track can be tracked only very near the image and go outside the near plane of the camera.